# What's the difference in this Sass code (one gives invalid css error, the other does not)?

Tags: html, css, sass

My code:

```
@for $j from 1 to 6 {
.text-#($j) { font-size: 15px * $j; }
}
```

doesn't run.  I even changed it to be more similar to the answers formatting with "through" by trying:

```
@for $j from 1 through 5 {
.text-#($j) { font-size: 15px * $j; }
}
```

Neither of those run, I get invalid css errors.
Error: Invalid CSS after "...m 1 through 5 {": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was ".text-#($j) { font-"
on line 2:27 of /stdin

> > @for $j from 1 through 5 {

**Then I check the solution (this is on freecodecamp), and it's this:**

```
  @for $j from 1 through 5 {
.text-#{$j} { font-size: 15px * $j; }
```

`}`

So... what the hell.  It runs just find when I copy and paste the listed solution, even though by all I can see, it's identical to my code.  Mine doesn't work, the other one does.  Not joking, I have looked this over several times and see no difference, how could this be?

Comment: I can see the difference at first look, your => `.text-#($j)`, other => `.text-#{$j}`, difference is about braces

Comment: `.text-#{$j}` is different from `.text-#($j)`, sass using `#{$variable}` syntax to dynamically insert variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SASS` uses `#{$var}` for declaring the variables so change that

**FROM**

`.text-#($j)`

**TO**

`.text-#{$j}`

the difference is braces